# compute simple math expression for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have a simple expression :
string s = "((5*5)-5)/10";

in console or windows form we can use this code
var tes = new DataTable().Compute(s,null);

But the problem is that DataTable() could not found.

Please help me find the solution for this

Comment: very unclear. insufficient information to answer.

Comment: Why do you need to have your expression as a string?

Comment: probably making a calculator app. there's definitely a few SO posts i've seen that link to some C# library that does all this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is another expression evaluator which makes quite a good impression:

http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Data` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) for Windows Phone 7 only includes the class `DataException`. The [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) class isn't in there, you don't have the full .NET Framework on Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 2):

You might try this instead :

http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2007/05/05/calculator-net-calculator-that-evaluates-math-expressions.aspx